# Name of training and test data files in NLP (BioBERT GitHub repo)

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, training-data, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I'm reading the `README.md` file of the [BioBERT GitHub repo](https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert#named-entity-recognition-ner):

> Let $NER_DIR indicate a folder for a single NER dataset which contains **train_dev.tsv, train.tsv, devel.tsv and test.tsv**. Also, set $OUTPUT_DIR as a directory for NER outputs (trained models, test predictions, etc). For example, when fine-tuning on the NCBI disease corpus,

I don't understand what's the point of using 4 different files for training and testing. To me, only 2 are needed: `train.tsv` and `test.tsv` (and optionally `valid.tsv`).

Could someone explain the meaning of these files and why they are needed?

Comment: I suspect the dev files are for validation - checking the hyper-params before doing a blind test

Comment: Train is training, dev is used for evaluation during training, test is held out test. That much is pretty normal. I'm not sure what train_dev would be, maybe you should just ask at their repo?